# Sysdig - how to merge two .scap files into a single .scap file?

Tags: linux, operating-system, filesystems, system-calls, sysdig

Using `Sysdig`, I captured logs into two individual files using the `sysdig -w filename.scap` command.
I would like to merge the two files into a single file and then be able to read it with the `sysdig -r merged_file_name.scap` command.

How can I merge the two .scap files into a single .scap file? I am looking for a similar functionality that `mergecap` can do for .pcap files